# About 3DES encryption / TripleDES different result in Objective-C and vb

Tags: objective-c, vb.net, cocoa

Now there is a demand, let me change the VB program of win to Mac cocoa program.
There is a 3DES encryption problem that bothers me
The encrypted strings of Mac and vb are completely different.

VB uses the TripleDES library, but Mac cannot import this library. I had to write one myself, but the results were different.

Mac：Objective-C，
Win：vb

I will upload my program, please help me. Thank you

```
//obj code
- (NSString*)doEncryptStr:(NSString*)originalStr { //withKey:(NSString*)key
NSString *key = @"XXXX";
uint8_t keyByte[kSecrectKeyLength];
//NSMutableData *keyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
int i;
for (i=0; i < [key length]/2; i++) {
    NSString *tempNumber = [key substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i * 2, 2)];
    //NSLog(@"tempNum == %@", tempNumber);
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tempNumber];
    //NSLog(@"scanner == %@", scanner.string);
    unsigned int temp;
    [scanner scanHexInt:&temp];
    Byte B = (Byte)(0xFF & temp);
    keyByte[i] = B;
}
//NSUTF8StringEncoding
NSData* data = [originalStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
size_t plainTextBufferSize = [data length];
const void *vplainText = (const void *)[data bytes];

CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
size_t movedBytes = 0;

bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
bufferPtr = malloc(bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

const void *vkey = (const void *) keyByte;
const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [gIv UTF8String];

ccStatus = CCCrypt(
                   kCCEncrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithmDES,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                   vkey,
                   kCCKeySizeDES,
                   vinitVec,
                   vplainText,
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void *)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes);

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
NSString *result = [GTMBase64 stringByEncodingData:myData];

NSLog(@"result == %@",result);

return result;
```

}

Below is the vb code

```
Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String) As String

    ' Convert the plaintext string to a byte array.
    Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = _
        System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)

    ' Create the stream.
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    ' Create the encoder to write to the stream.
    Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, _
        TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(), _
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
    encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
    encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    ' Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string.
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the key correctly? Also, on the VB side it *seems* like UTF8 and on the Objective-C side you use UTF16.

Comment: There is no problem with the key. I don’t know much about net code,
I started with UFT8, but the number of bits in the encrypted string is completely different from win. win has 140 bits, but mac has only 70

Comment: Ok - take a look at https://gist.github.com/marsepu/3854078 where e.g. the algo is ```kCCAlgorithm3DES```.